# Cannot start react-native server

Tags: react-native

I have React-native project. When I want to start it, I run `npm start` or `yarn start`, and I get this:

```
 $ yarn startyarn run v1.7.0
$ react-native-scripts start
11:36:37: Starting packager...
***ERROR STARTING PACKAGER***
No issue with doctor-watchman-version
No issue with doctor-problem-checking-watchman-version
No issue with doctor-both-app-and-exp-json
No issue with doctor-schema-validation
No issue with doctor-validate-asset-fields
No issue with doctor-schema-validation-exception
No issue with doctor-unversioned
No issue with doctor-versions-endpoint-failed
No issue with doctor-invalid-sdk-version
No issue with doctor-node-modules-missing
No issue with doctor-react-native-not-installed
Starting Metro Bundler on port 19001.
Metro Bundler ready.

jest-haste-map: Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler.
  Usually this happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig` file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg repository in your project.
  Error: Watchman error: too many pending cache jobs. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.
```

If I uninstall wathcman Packeger get stucked.
Creating `.watchmanconfig` file, also didn't help.

(Linux Mint OS)

Hours of searching. I have not found a solution yet :(

Comment: do you have watchman installed on your computer already?

Comment: yes I have it installed

Comment: check this thread, looks like similar issue https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/346

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm r -g watchman
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install watchman
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention before. I have Linux mint OS

Answer (score 0):

```
watchman shutdown-server
```

This command from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/346#issuecomment-398266417) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ npm install
```

If you are using visual studio, in the bottom of the view there is button to restart. click that and run